# Getting the user's Country ISO or Country name

Tags: ruby, windows, iso

Is there a way to get the current country\ISO name (United States\US) from the OS (without using IP address since i don't know if the relevant user will have internet access).

The relevant OS is Windows (I know this could be done on C#).

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621985/reading-the-regional-location-setting-country-code-in-windows-using-ruby

Comment: @Casper Thanks a lot! most certainly helpful!

Comment: The gem `locale` will give you locale information (not geo location though).

Comment: See my updated answer now. It will give you the country name: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621985/reading-the-regional-location-setting-country-code-in-windows-using-ruby